# Can't unselect items in ListBox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, listbox

I create few `ListBox`es in my partial view like below:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Executors, executors, new { @class = "selectpicker form-control filter-selector", @title = Messages.ChooseExecutors, multiple = "" })
```

The next in function I try to unselect all selected items:

```
$('select.filter-selector option:selected').prop("selected", false);
```

Function works perfect because it executes a some yet work. And I added a log to ths function body it returns two selected `option`s as well as I selected. But it doesn't unselect items and doesn't give any errors in the console.
What do I doing wrong?

**ADDED**
Generated html:

```
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select show-tick form-control filter-selector open">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-id="Statuses" title="Новое, Принято в работу" aria-expanded="true">
        <span class="filter-option pull-left">Новое, Принято в работу</span>&nbsp;<span class="bs-caret"><span class="caret"></span></span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu open" role="combobox" style="max-height: 168px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 92px;">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="listbox" aria-expanded="true" style="max-height: 156px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 80px;">
            <li data-original-index="0"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="text">На проверке</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="1"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="text">Отклонено</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="2" class="selected"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="true"><span class="text">Новое</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="3" class="selected"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="true"><span class="text">Принято в работу</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="4"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="text">Возвращено на доработку</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="5"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="text">Принято</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="6"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="text">Завершено</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
       </ul>
   </div>
   <select class="selectpicker form-control filter-selector" id="Statuses" multiple="" name="Statuses" title="Укажите статусы" tabindex="-98">
        <option value="a59f921d-93e7-4a23-b041-53fc544e7d4e">На проверке</option>
        <option value="1bb61f3c-03d7-4f53-83e5-ca5e6c9fe4b7">Отклонено</option>
        <option value="96110d07-d9b4-442c-9d36-55c6505ec8eb">Новое</option>
        <option value="a28af5c3-27d4-487e-8d86-8386abdbebca">Принято в работу</option>
        <option value="c8054a54-c252-4b89-b12c-2fe3c00c0c91">Возвращено на доработку</option>
        <option value="e944d0b5-760b-4d2a-8000-70cb2033d9ca">Принято</option>
        <option value="f4e97d91-b9cb-4963-838f-c86e71f8a34c">Завершено</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: @Satpal, yeah, of course. Wait, please.

Comment: Works fine in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/es39ghah/). Not related, but remove `multiple = "" - the `ListBoxFor()` method adds `multiple="multiple"` already

Comment: @StephenMuecke, it works perfect for simple `<select>` but Bootstrap generates a lot of additional html.

Comment: `$("#Statuses").val([])` it will work, try this.

Comment: There is nothing in that html which would make any difference (unless there is some css which is hiding the select, and a jquery plugin that is replacing the `<select>` with its own html)

Comment: @TechVision, it doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Have just seen the edit - and yes, the `<select>` is replaced with the `<div>` above it

Comment: are you using  `selectpicker` of bootstrap.

Comment: @TechVision, yeah, I wrote it in tags and a code.

Comment: `$('#Statuses').selectpicker('val', []);` use this.

Comment: @TechVision, many thx! It will be more beautiful solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for help!
I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28111340/select-all-unselect-all-in-bootstrap-select-plugin). I didn't know that Bootstrap replaces `<select>`. So, this code works for me:

```
$('select.filter-selector option:selected').prop("selected", false);
$('select.filter-selector.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```